# CSS: Positioning a child element relative to its parent using any position property on the parent

Tags: css, position, css-position, specifications, absolute

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
   <p>Position me relative to my parent.</p>
</div>
```

In the above HTML, let's say I want that `p` element to go to the bottom of the parent `div`. It's common to use the following CSS:

```
div {
   position: relative;
}

p {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

My question is: **Could I also achieve this by using any position declaration(other than static) for the parent?**

I've been trying to find concrete proof of this but the CSS spec is inaccessible(won't load) and various reference sites like MDN and w3schools say "An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor," which is a little vague.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

In my tests, it seems that any ancestor that has a position other than the default of `static` can work for setting the child relative to.

https://jsfiddle.net/saywxme4/16/

Hoping to hear from someone who knows for sure on this. References from authoritative sources are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is:

> Could I also achieve this [positioning the p element at the bottom] by using any position declaration(other than
> static) for the parent?

Yes

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> A positioned element is an element whose computed position value is
> either relative, absolute, fixed, or sticky. (In other words, it's
> anything except static.)

Comment: Ahh, thanks for pointing this out. In some instances of the term "positioned element" it's not clear that it has a specific meaning. w3schools, for example, does not seem to define "positioned element." Appreciate it.